# fontawesome package in w32tex

Tags: fontawesome

I want to use the fontawesome package in w32tex. I downloaded the latest version (4.4.0 2015-07-30) from CTAN. I put it (maybe) to the right place and prepared the following simple source file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontawesome} 
\begin{document}

\faFlag \faRocket \faTwitter \faCopy

\end{document}
```

After compiling the file with lualatex, I got the following error:

```
! LuaTeX error ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-fontloader.lua:5496:
 font loading failed.
<to be read again> 
\scan_stop: 
l.45 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
?
```

I am wondering what was the problem. Is it the case that I put the package to the wrong folder? (Whenever I wanted to use new packages, it has worked if I put them to: w32tex > share > texmf-dist > tex > latex ) Is some package still missing? I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me how to use fontawesome package in my environment, i.e. w32tex in Windows 8.1.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install the package?  Manually or did you use utilities from your TeX-distro?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I just *downloaded* it from CTAN: [link] (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome?lang=en)

Comment: That is the problem; the installation needs some post-working.  Remove the files you have installed and install the package with `tlmgr install fontawesome` at a command prompt (if you use TeXLive distro)

Comment: I'm afraid I am not using TeXLive -- I am using TeXstudio/TeXworks. Does somebody know how to use the package in TeXstudio?

Comment: TeXstudio and TeXworks are text editors.  They are not TeX distributions.  MiKTeX and TeXLive are distributions.

Answer (score 2):

How to install fontawesome in W32TeX

(1) Rearrange downloaded files as follows:

```
texmf-local/doc/fonts/fontawesome/README.md
texmf-local/doc/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.tex
texmf-local/doc/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf

texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesomeone.enc
texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesomethree.enc
texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesometwo.enc
texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesome.map
texmf-local/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf
texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesomethree.tfm
texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm
texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesomeone.tfm
texmf-local/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb

texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-xeluatex.tex
texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomeone.fd
texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesometwo.fd
texmf-local/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomethree.fd
```

(2) Run mktexlsr

(3) Run updmap --add fontawesome.map